# Jquery or some Script

Tags: scroll, popup, tooltip

Does anybody knows name of script in this example - http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/categories/departments/bedroom/16285/ When rollover mouse on goods - show popup with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though IKEA uses the [Prototype JavaScript framework](http://www.prototypejs.org/)

Comment: i mean does anybody knows/see samples of effects like this  http://www.sadochek.com.ua/hover.jpg . when move mouse over image expands mini layer with info